# Subscript out of range when replaying macro changing tab color

Tags: excel, vba, colors, tabs, subscript

I recorded a macro doing this: changing the color of a sheet tab, and then setting it to auto-color. The resulting code is this:

```
Sub Makro4()
' Makro4 Makro
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("GBP").Tab
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
        .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
    End With
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("GBP").Tab
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

When I replay it, by writing makro4 in the immediate window OR by placing this code on a button on the worksheet, it doesn't work:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("GBP").Tab
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
        .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
    End With
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("GBP").Tab
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    'Makro4
End Sub
```

The .colorindex-line produces a "Subscript out of range". Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `xlColorIndexAutomatic` instead of `xlAutomatic`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's recorded by Excel. Both variables hold the same value: -4105

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem.  Very frustrating when recorded macros can't actually be executed.  Instead of `xlAutomatic`, you need to use: `xlColorIndexNone`.  [Source](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/9/16/remove-excel-tab-colors-with-vba).

This response probably too late to be useful to you, but just in case someone else stumbles across the link with the same problem...